# React Native: Issue with TextInput - Keyboard Dismisses Unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently facing an issue in my React Native project related to the TextInput component. When I focus on the input field, the keyboard dismisses unexpectedly. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Type something..."
        onFocus={() => handleFocus()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function handleFocus() {
  console.log('Input field focused!');
  // Additional logic if needed
}
```

Despite having a basic onFocus handler, the keyboard dismisses without any apparent reason. I've tested this on both Android and iOS, and the behavior is consistent.

I've checked for any interference from external libraries, and there don't seem to be any conflicts in my styling. Can someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this unexpected keyboard dismissal issue in React Native? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding onChangeText?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at code this shouldn't happen. Still I tried to reproduce it [here](https://snack.expo.dev/f9PGj9hwo?platform=ios), But no luck and it's just working fine.

I would suggest to take elimination approach for troubleshooting cause -

1. First, Test your app on some other device/environment. If it works then that means your device/env has some issue.
2. Write down bare minimum code in isolated component and render only that in your app.
3. If above step resolves issue, then that means rest of the code (May be
   parent component is tampering with keyboard). You can debug by removing doubtful code one by one from parent/child component and test it simultaneously to identify culprit.
4. If above (#2) doesn't works then start removing doubtful third party packages one by one and simultaneously test if your issue is resolved.

Hope this will help you identify the issue. best of luck.